# Multiple socket.on("connection") in one Application

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

i building at the moment a websocket application and i using socket.io for this.
I have separated my different application parts into different socket files like below.

My question is, are the multiple socket.on('connection') a bad practice or is this way okay to go?

sockets.js

```
const chatSocket = require('./chat');
const otherSocket = require('./other');

const sockets = (server) => {
    const io = socket(server);

    chatSocket(io);
    otherSocket(io);
}

module.exports = sockets;
```

chat.js

```
const chatSocket = (io) => {
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        // Socket functions
    });
}

module.exports = chatSocket;
```

other.js

```
const otherSocket = (io) => {
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        // Socket functions
    });
}

module.exports = otherSocket;
```

Anyways already thank you for your help and have a nice day :)

ccc

Comment: It's fine, you're passing same instance to both files

Answer (score 0):

It is ok if these are getting used for different purposes. But better to minimize the open socket connect at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by better? And based on what reason?